# PUT and Delete Request in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Django, I was wondering How to code PUT request and Delete method in my Django REST API Project.

I have tried to follow with many tutorials, but none working with my kind of code.

The code I tried looks like this

```html
def put(self, request, pk):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializers(snippet, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
def delete(self, request, pk):
    snippet = self.get_object(pk)
    snippet.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

But getting message method not allowed

The following is my Models.py

```html
from django.db import models


class Users(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    profile_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    profile_picture = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The following is my serializers.py

```html
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Users
from .models import UserPost


class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'


class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'


class UserPostSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPost
        fields = '__all__'
```

The following code contains my Views.py

```html
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from .models import Users
from .models import UserPost
from .serializers import UserSerializers, UserPostSerializers


class UsersList(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        User_details = Users.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializers(User_details, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class UserDetail(APIView):
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Users.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Users.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializers(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Users.objects.all()
        serializer_class = UserSerializer

        @action(methods=['put'], detail=False)
        def filter_by_something(self, request):
            something = request.data.get('that_something')
            queryset = Users.objects.filter(something__exact=something)
            return Response(self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True).data)
```

The following code contains urls.py

```html
from sys import path

from django.urls import include
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from app import views
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()



router.register('user_details', UserDetailViewSet)
urlpatterns = [path('api/', include(router.urls)), ...]
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^User_details/', views.UsersList.as_view()),
    url(r'^User_details/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/', views.UserDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^userpost_details/', views.UsersPostList.as_view()),

]
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Comment: Which view did you add the PUT/DELETE to ? What url did you perform the PUT/DELETE against ?

Comment: @Linovia Views.py in the app folder, url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/User_details/

Comment: Your PUT/DELETE are likely to work on a specific resource, not the list of resources which is why you get the erreur

Answer (score 1):

Define `put` & `delete` methods in `UsersDetail` class.

```
class UsersDetail(APIView):
 def put(self, request, pk):
   // code

 def delete(self, request, pk):
   //code
```

If the above does not work also add `http_method_names`

```
class UsersDetail(APIView):
 http_method_names = ['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
```

class `APIView` inherits from class `View` defined in the base file of Django. `dispatch` method will check `http_method_names` for valid method. `PUT` and `DELETE` is listed as valid methods along with others.

Reference: `django/views/generic/base.py`

```
  class View(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Try to dispatch to the right method; if a method doesn't exist,
        # defer to the error handler. Also defer to the error handler if the
        # request method isn't on the approved list.
        if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
            handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
        else:
            handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def http_method_not_allowed(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.warning('Method Not Allowed (%s): %s', request.method, request.path,
            extra={
                'status_code': 405,
                'request': request
            }
        )
        return http.HttpResponseNotAllowed(self._allowed_methods())
```

Answer (score 0):

In urls.py you should declare a router object that maps your ViewSets to DRF:

```
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('user_details', UserDetailViewSet)
urlpatterns = [path('api/', include(router.urls)), ...]
```

UserDetailViewSet must be declared in api\views.py (api is the directory for DRF application)

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

class UserDetailViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserDetail.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer

    @action(methods=['put'], detail=False)
    def filter_by_something(self, request):
        something = request.data.get('that_something')
        queryset = UserDetail.objects.filter(something__exact=something)
        return Response(self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True).data)
```

Then you will make PUT requests on http:\\your_website\api\user_details\filter_by_something

Try something like this. It should work!

Comment: I added the code in URLs.py(project folder) and views.py (app folder) and I had to create a new serializer class in serializers.py(app folder)its code looks like ```class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'
```      Now where and How should I ad PUT and DELETE request code in the code?

Comment: and I am getting an error ```in UserDetailViewSet
    queryset = UserDetail.objects.all()
AttributeError: type object 'UserDetail' has no attribute 'objects'```

Comment: UserDetail is the model declared in your application: ```class UserDetail(models.Model): ....```. You import it in api\views.py like this: ```from your_app.models import UserDetail```. In your case, i think it's not UserDetail, it's simply Users

Comment: I have edited the question and code as you Said, but am getting an error in UserDetail
    class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
NameError: name 'viewsets' is not defined can you check that edited code in my question?

Comment: just insert: ```from rest_framework import viewsets```